# How to pass the params to the getInitialProps method in _app.js file in next js from the url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

the below is the getInitialProps method for MyApp.

```
MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ctx}) => {
    const { siteHeaderCollection } = await getHeaderData(ctx.query.lang)
    const { siteFooterCollection } = await getFooterData(ctx.query.lang)
    return {
        locale: ctx.query.lang,
        header: siteHeaderCollection,
        footer: siteFooterCollection,
    }
}
```

I need to pass the slug to this getInitialProps method. could anyone please guide on how to pass the params which are fetched from the path url

Answer (score 1):

To pass the slug as a parameter to the `getInitialProps` method like

```js
MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ ctx }) => {
    const { query: { lang, slug } } = ctx; // Retrieve the slug from the 
    query object

    // Fetch header and footer data using the slug
    const { siteHeaderCollection } = await getHeaderData(lang, slug);
    const { siteFooterCollection } = await getFooterData(lang, slug);

    return {
        locale: lang,
        header: siteHeaderCollection,
        footer: siteFooterCollection,
    };
};
```

In this code snippet, `slug` is extracted from `ctx.query`, assuming that the slug parameter is passed as part of the URL path. You can then use this `slug` variable to fetch the appropriate header and footer data using the `getHeaderData` and `getFooterData` functions, passing the `lang` and `slug` as parameters.

Make sure to update the `getHeaderData` and `getFooterData` functions accordingly to accept the `slug` parameter and fetch the data based on the slug value.

Comment: As I added a comment for first answer, the ctx itself is coming as an empty object otherwise it is printing two different values when I am logging the ctx.asPath value

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [NextJS documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/get-initial-props), you can find the following:

> **getInitialProps** is an async function that can be added to the default exported React component for the page. It will run on both the server-side and again on the client-side during page transitions. The result of the function will be forwarded to the React component as **props**.

This means, whatever you return in the `getInitialProps` function will be passed as `props` in that component. (in your case, `locale`, `header` and `footer`)

**Little note**: `getInitialProps` is a legacy API. NextJS recommends using `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` instead.

You can access the current slug from the context:

```js
    const { query: { lang, slug } } = ctx;
```

And add it to the return object

```js
 return {
        slug,
        locale: lang,
        header: siteHeaderCollection,
        footer: siteFooterCollection,
    }
```

Comment: the only reason i need to pass that slug is to handle the custom 404 page. But the ctx itself is  coming as an empty object when giving the incorrect slug in the url

Comment: I am able to get the lang and slug but the only issue that i am seeing now is that it is executing twice and logging the correct values first time and getting undefined next

Comment: If I understand well, you would like to send the user to a 404 page if the slug is incorrect? If so you can simply return `{ notFound: true }` after checking that the slug  doesn't exist

Comment: Even if the slug is incorrect,i need the header and footer based on lang variable

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox so I can better help you?